# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS blocking access from other network PCs

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, laptop

One Ubuntu 12.04 laptop connects to the internet OK, but I can't ping that laptop. I can ping any PC on the network from any other, but this one we can call it (W).

It is causing a issue as the (W) PC can not see the other PCs on the network and we like to share files.

I will add I have checked the firewall and even disabled it and checked to make sure port 22 is listening.

Comment: What's the IP address of each machine? Find it with `ifconfig | grep "net addr" `then click on the grey _edit_ link above and to the left.

Comment: I'd love to see: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 0):

please check if app armor is installed.,it is similar to selinux.,  if yes remove by following below commands:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop

update-rc.d -f apparmor remove

apt-get remove apparmor apparmor-utils
```

also re-check your network configuration and synchronize your system clock., some times it may be an issue too

Hope this helps.. cheers